# Calling instance methods from init

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it proper to call instance methods of a class from that class's `init` method? I'm in an ARC environment, and I'm not certain what I can and cannot do from `init`. Apple's documentation says [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6) but I don't really understand why exactly that is.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a discussion about it: [Using Accessors in Init and Dealloc](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-27-using-accessors-in-init-and-dealloc.html). There is no real answer, it depends. Be sure there are no side effects if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

Init methods are used to set initial values to the instance variables of the class.

Check:

[Why shoudn't I use accessor methods in init methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424382/why-shoudnt-i-use-accessor-methods-in-init-methods)