# memory management on the iPhone with viewDidUnload

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If you set a property to nil in viewDidUnload do you need to release it again in dealloc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but:

- You don't need to check for that case. `[nil release]` is fine.
- You can't count on `viewDidUnload` being called.

So just release as normal in `-dealloc`.

Of course, you must make sure that you actually released the previous object.  You implicitly do this *if you used the synthesized setter*:

```
self.myProperty = nil;  // good
// or
[self setMyProperty:nil]; // also good
```

But setting the ivar to nil will leak:

```
self->myProperty = nil; // leaky as a sieve
// or 
myProperty = nil; // as useful as a screen door on a submarine
```

These are common errors.

Also note that setting properties to nil in `-dealloc` is a bad idea. As Kendall points out in the comments, you may unexpectedly invoke KVO behavior.  There's a fuller discussion at [Properties in dealloc: release then set to nil? or simply release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402234/properties-in-dealloc-release-then-set-to-nil-or-simply-release/3402247#3402247).

Comment: can I do property = nil in viewDidUnload  and [property release] in dealloc? will this over-release the property?

Comment: Yes, that approach leaks.  It does not invoke the setter (which will release the old value); it just writes a new value over the old one.  Since the old value is never released, it leaks. 

You must be certain to write `self.property = nil`, not `property = nil`.

Comment: Note that you should not use self.myProperty = nil in a dealloc statement.  There you should release the object directly so as to avoid triggering KVC notifications.

Comment: @Kendall Yes, you are correct.  I didn't think there was any suggestion of using assignment to nil in `-dealloc`.  But I've updated my post to clarify.