# UITableViewCell dealloc method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have `UITableViewCell` in my app:

```
@interface ResultCell : UITableViewCell {
IBOutlet UILabel *name;
IBOutlet UILabel *views;
IBOutlet UILabel *time;
IBOutlet UILabel *rating;
IBOutlet UILabel *artist;

IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *views;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *time;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *artist;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *img;

@end
```

And all of this `IBOutlet` connected in the Xib file to `UILabel`....

This is how i create each cell:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ResultCell";
ResultCell *cell = (ResultCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){
    UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultCell" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        cell = (ResultCell *) vc.view;
}

cell.name.text = item.name;
cell.views.text = item.viewCount;
cell.rating.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%",item.rating];
cell.time.text = item.timeStr;
cell.artist.text = item.artist;
```

And i want to know if in the `ResultCell` class i need to implement a dealoc method and release the `UILabel` ? or it's ok like what i done? i am using Non-ARC because it is an old project.

Comment: why do you create e UIViewController, and then take the cell, instead of a cell? your vc.view seems to be a UIView, not a cell.

Comment: In this case, yes you would need to.  However, it seems pointless to have all of those retain properties since they will be retained by their superview anyway.  Why not change them all to `assign`?  Then you won't have to deal with `dealloc`.

Comment: why do u need a UIViewController for ResultCell class?

Comment: because using a UIViewController for loading a cell from a NIB is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every retained property or instance variable has to be released and IBOutlets are no different. Because you use properties, the preferable way to do this is:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    self.name = nil;
    self.views = nil;
    //... and so on
    [super dealloc];
}
```

By the way, you don't need to declare "redundant" instance variables for your properties like this:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *name;
```

It was needed a long time ago (AFAIR in times of XCode 3), but now the compiler will generate them automatically for each declared property.

Comment: +1, but just a minor complaint that I read:  Don't use `self.XXX = nil` inside `dealloc` and instead just release the backing property.  This will avoid any potential KVO issues (It is best to avoid `self` inside of `init` and `dealloc` wherever possible)

Comment: Link to the above info -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402234/properties-in-dealloc-release-then-set-to-nil-or-simply-release#comment3539445_3402247

Comment: IBOutlets are held by the view and can be weak -- except for top level objects

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yes, that is also true (as I noted in a comment on the original post).  However, in the case that OP doesn't make them assign properties this is a sound response.

Answer (score 0):

You can make all labels in the custom table viewcell as assign if you need it **retain** it you have to release in dealloc method and assign nil in `viewDidUnload`.It avoids memory leaks.

Comment: May valid for the older version
Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713841/10632772

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to write the `dealloc` method in `ResultCell` class to release the objects that you synthesize to avoid memoryleak. For more understanding refer the link http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Answer (score 0):

1. You are type casting `UIView` as `ResultCell`, instead of creating `UITableViewCell` instance with cell identifier.
2. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return `nil`, thus creating large number of `UIViewController` instances
3. Since you are returning `UIViewController`'s view, memory management will become tricky. You also need to release view controller instance after the cell is released by the table view. This will require to store all vc instances and release them later on. Currently all vc instances are causing memory leaks.

To avoid these unnecessary complications you need to follow standard techniques. That being said, you need to create a separate XIB and class files for cell, use UINib to load the table view cell from xib. Refer this [tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/02/28/speeding-up-table-view-cell-loading-with-uinib.html).

Cheers!
Amar

Comment: Solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713841/10632772

Answer (score -1):

use something like-

```
ResultCell *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ResultCell"  owner:self    options:nil] lastObject];
```

instead of

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultCell" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Make sure u make the `ResultCell.xib` files' owner to  `ResultCell` class.

And **Yes**, as the `UILabel` and `UIImageView`  are `retained` properties, they shall be released in the `dealloc` method of `ResultCell` class.